# how to remove repeating value from a list but let reside one of them list using a loop..i have tried my best to figure it out but couldn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list

```
unconfirmed = ['adeen','shahzaib','zaid','shahzaib','shahzaib','shahzaib']
while 'shahzaib'in unconfirmed:
    unconfirmed.remove('shahzaib')
print(unconfirmed)
```

Comment: convert to set, then convert back to list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates in the lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-the-lists)

Answer (score 1):

Since the [set](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp) data type automatically removes duplicate elements, you can turn your list into a set, and then turn it back into a list.

```
unconfirmed = ['adeen', 'shahzaib', 'zaid', 'shahzaib', 'shahzaib', 'shahzaib']
unconfirmed = list(set(unconfirmed))

# Test
print(unconfirmed)
```

Comment: thanks for your help man!! really appreciate it